# I need to make a loop for the unique output, which is copied to different columns in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Unique_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLastRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

Set xRng = Worksheets("Data1").Range(Range("C15"))
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xRng.Copy Range("B21")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("B21:B" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Set xRng = Worksheets("Data2").Range(Range("O15"))
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xRng.Copy Range("N21")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("N21:N" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Set xRng = Worksheets("Data3").Range(Range("AA15"))
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xRng.Copy Range("Z21")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("Z21:Z" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

I need to loop this. Alternatively, I have to repeat this 31 times (max days in one month). The space between the output columns are always the same. I.e the difference between B21, N21; Z21 etc..

Any suggestions? Otherwise I will just do it manually.

Comment: Remove all `On Error Resume Next` lines. This just hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur. Instead fix your errors! If you don't fix them your code cannot work properly by just hiding the error messages. [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Are the sheets named "Data1" to "Data31"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that will help:

```
Private Sub Unique_Click()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xLastRow As Long
    Dim xLastRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim colNo As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    For colNo = 3 To 27 Step 12
        Set xRng = Worksheets("Data1").Cells(15, colNo)
        If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        xRng.Copy Cells(21, colNo - 1)
        xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(21, colNo - 1), Cells(xLastRow, colNo - 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next colNo
End Sub
```

You just need to loop through ColNo (step = 12, meaning we are adding 12 columns with each loop), starting with column C (3) and ending with column AA (27).

I would also suggest adding a sheet name to `xRng.Copy Cells(21, colNo - 1)` just to make sure the code is running in the right place.

One more tip - you don't need to use `On Error Resume Next` so many times. It stays active until you "turn it off" with `On Error GoTo 0`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually you should never use `On Error Resume Next` like that, this is a very bad practice (especially with a loop). If there really happens an error in the loop then the outcome is pretty much unpredictable. See [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) for how to implement error handling properly.

Comment: Also the source data is not all on sheet "Data1".

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. This didn't work with my data, so I will just do it the old way. I will correct the "On Error Resume Next"-issue.

Comment: Hi @Jan is there any way we can help you with accommodating your file? Maybe post a screenshot of your data set so that we can see what's happening? Cheers